# Multiple Class Singletons in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class that creates two singletons.  Will this create 2 separate singletons and keep a reference to each, or am I just overwriting the same singleton?

```
+(ListingManager *)sharedListings
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ListingManager *sharedListings = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedListings = [[ListingManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedListings;
}

+(ListingManager *)sharedSellingListings
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ListingManager *sharedSellingListings = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedSellingListings = [[ListingManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSellingListings;
}
```

Comment: Why all the down votes? I think it's a valid question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will keep 2 separate singletons and keep a reference to each.

this is because of the static variables declared in each method are separate and are what retain the singleton object

Comment: Ok, thanks, thats what I was wondering, but I didn't know if I was bound to only have one per class. I will accept soon